# LESS - how to refer bootstrap css classes in less?

Tags: css, less

I want to refer multiple css classes in one less class but I keep getting following error, any idea what I maybe doing wrong here? 
I newbie to LESS, so if there is any better option to achieve this, I would be happy to try it out as well.

```
NameError: .btn is undefined
in qx.less on line 2, column 2:
```

Here is my setup

```
<link rel='stylesheet'         href='/webjars/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet/less"    href='/assets/less/qx.less'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/webjars/less/1.7.0/less.min.js'></script>
```

Content of qx.less - here I am trying to create qx-button which combines .btn and .btn-success of bootstrap.

```
#qx-button {
    .btn;
    .btn-success;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19780066/2712740. In short, each linked less file is preprocessed separately and no linked css files are involved in preprocessing (thus no CSS classes from `bootstrap.min.css` are visible in `qx.less`). If you want to reference some classes from external CSS files you need to explicitly import these files into your less file (e.g. `@import (less, reference) ".../bootstrap.min.css";`. See Less [import options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options)).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put properties... or you should remove the selectors .btn && .btn-success

```
#qx-button{

.btn{
   background-color: #22f;
}
.btn-success{
  border: 3px solid #23e;
}

}
```

Comment: But I want .btn and .btn-success to use all the properties defined in bootstrap.css - so that my code would be cleaner as it refers only one css class. Am I missing something here?

Comment: you are loading bootstrap.min before qx.less so every btn will have the same properties all along your webpage by Default (inheritance). Unless you redefining .btn in qx.less documents.

Comment: Does your .btn doesn't have the same properties as defined in bootstrap.min.css.. in other words do the buttons looks like the one from bootstrap' webpage ?

Comment: I want to use out of the box properties of btn and btn-success but want to refer qx-button in my html instead of "btn btn-success".

Answer (score -1):

Than on your Html document you could use a different HTML element like 'span' instead of 'button'

original :: this will use bootstrap css

```
<button class="add_to_cart btn btn-success">
   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
   My name is Hemant
</button>
```

modified:: this will be customized

```
<style type="text/css">
//THis will go to your less file
span#qx-button.btn.btn-success{
    background-color: #f44;
}
</style>

<span id="qx-button" class="btn btn-success">
  Hello How are you?
</span>
```

The #id is optionnal (you don't really need it) you could write down

```
 <style type="text/css">
    span.btn.btn-success{
        background-color: #f44;
    }
    </style>

<span class="btn btn-success"></span>
```